# How can I use xTaskCreate in class and use its arguments in static task method

Tags: c++, static, esp32, void-pointers, freertos

I'm working on a personnal project to learn about FreeRTOS. I have several esp32s2 with PSRAM and native USB.

I made a small example to go deeper in my problem: I can not manage to manipulate the attribute of my C++ class inside the static Task method called through xTaskCreate C function.

Here is a piece of simplified code:

```
class Object {
  public:
    Object(int p_Param) : 
      m_Attribute(p_Param)
    {
       xTaskCreate(
        Task,
        "Task",
        1024,
        this,
        3,
        NULL);
    }

    static void Task(void* p_pParam);

  private:
    int m_Attribute;
};

void Object::Task(void* p_pParam) {
  Object* p_pThis = static_cast<Object*>(p_pParam);

  while(1) {
    Serial.println("Ok");
    Serial.println(p_pThis->m_Attribute);
    delay(500);
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Start");
  Object test(25);
}

void loop() {

}
```

The result I have is the following:

```
15:47:57.685 -> Ok
15:47:57.685 -> 1073484684
...
```

I was expecting to have this in loop:

```
15:47:57.685 -> Ok
15:47:57.685 -> 20
...
```

Sources:
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/esp32-xtaskcreatepinnedtocore-usage-in-a-class/630469
https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2085

Comment: Don't allocate Object test(25); on stack (as local variable in setup function.) b/c test object get's destroyed when leaving setup. You need persistent memory (from heap) so try e.g. 'new Object test(25);'

Comment: Why is `m_Attribute` private?

Comment: @HS2 Indeed a solution could be to use Object* l_Object= new Object(25);