# How to create multiple thread within one class with FreeRTOS on Esp32s2?

Tags: c++, multithreading, esp32, freertos

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75813999/how-can-i-use-xtaskcreate-in-class-and-use-its-arguments-in-static-task-method) I managed to create a simple thread on a custom C++ class.

I want to go further in my research on FreeRTOS and Esp32: I wish to create multiple independant threads.

Here is my code:

The Thread class

```
class Thread {
  public:
    Thread(const char * p_Name="", int p_Priority=1, int p_Core=0) {
      xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(Task, p_Name, 4096, this, p_Priority, &this->m_TaskHandle, p_Core);
    }

    virtual void run() = 0;

  protected:
    static void Task(void* p_pPtr) {
      Thread* p_pThis = static_cast<Thread*>(p_pPtr);
      p_pThis->run();
    }

    TaskHandle_t m_TaskHandle;
};
```

The object that inherit from Thread class:

```
class Object : public Thread{
  public:
    Object(int p_Attr, const char* p_Name)
      : Thread(p_Name),
        m_Attr(p_Attr)
    {
    }

    ~Object() = default;

    virtual void run() override {
      for(;;) {
        Serial.println(m_Attr);
        vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
      }      
    }

  private:
    int m_Attr;
};
```

The Builder object that embed multiple objects:

```
class Builder {
  public:
    Builder() :
      m_Object_A(15, "A"),
      m_Object_B(20, "B")
    {
    }

  private:
    Object m_Object_A;
    Object m_Object_B;
};
```

And the main:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(4000);

  Serial.println("Start");
  Builder* BobTheBuilder = new Builder();
}
```

The app crash after 4 seconds when the memory allocation is made. If I have a single object, it works but with multiple it crashes. Do I need a destructor for the Thread object ? If yes, why ?

Comment: The thread is started from the constructor of `Thread`. At this point the derived  class `Object` has not yet been constructed. So the virtual function call to `run` will fail or there is at least a race condition on the full object being created.

Comment: Can you give me some advices on how to fix that ? Shall I move the thread's start in an init method I call later ? Or should I use a thread_safe mecanism like a mutex or a semaphore ?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, mixing raw FreeRTOS with C++ can cause some issues. ESP-IDF provides C++ support, making the threading in C++ with FreeRTOS a bit easier.

I would recommend using the [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) to get threads working.

You could do something like this.
Instead of creating a Thread class, give the class a thread on creation and let that one run

```
#include <thread>                // For the std::thread
#include <esp_pthread.h>         // For the thread config
#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>   // FreeRTOS

class Object{
  public:
    Object(int p_Attr, const char* p_Name)
    :m_Attr(p_Attr)
    {
        // Create a new thread config
        auto cfg        = esp_pthread_get_default_config();
        cfg.thread_name = p_Name;
        esp_pthread_set_cfg(&cfg); // The next pthread or C++ thread will have this config

        // Start the thread  
        m_Thread = std::thread(&Object::run, this);
    }

    // Deconstructor
    ~Object(){
      stopped = true;  // Stop the loop
      m_Thread.join(); // Cleanup the thread
    }

    virtual void run() {
      while(!stopped){
        Serial.println(m_Attr);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{2000});
      }
    }

  private:
    int m_Attr;
    std::thread m_Thread;
    bool stopped = false; // Flag to make sure the loop can exit
};
```

The builder can stay the same:

```
class Builder {
  public:
    Builder() :
      m_Object_A(15, "A"),
      m_Object_B(20, "B")
    {
    }

  private:
    Object m_Object_A;
    Object m_Object_B;
};
```

In the main a stop was added to demonstrate thread cleanup:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(4000);

  Serial.println("Start");
  Builder* BobTheBuilder = new Builder();

  // Let the thread run for 10 seconds
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{10});

  // Destroy the builder and it's objects
  Serial.println("Stopping");
  delete BobTheBuilder;
  BobTheBuilder = nullptr;
}
```

Note:
As ESP-IDF 5.0 supports C++20, you could even opt for using [std::jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) (basically a [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) implementation of std::thread). But you have to be carefull with the deconstructor of the std::jthread, as it can only be called from a pthread or C++ thread *not* from a FreeRTOS task. (As stated in their [documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s3/api-guides/cplusplus.html#multithreading))